# Adding Mouse-Over summary from a dll

Tags: c#, .net, intellisense

Our Organization is creating a global dll for all of our projects in the coming years.  The dll is created, and implemented for use, but I'm having a problem getting the summary tags to work.  When hovering over a specified method from the dll, I want to be able to display the summary for any developer, so they will not have to go into the dll itself.

I came here and found this question: [How to add a mouse-over summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284001/how-to-add-a-mouse-over-summary)

The problem is, the summary is not displaying when the method is being called from outside the dll itself (however, from inside the dll the summary is displaying just fine).

Is there any way to "import" the summary from the dll so it will be displayed when any user hovers over the appropriate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're not adding this project to your various solutions, but instead are building it once and copying the .dll around, and browsing out to the .dll when you add references in your projects.

When you copy this .dll around, are you also copying the ProjectName.xml file? That's where the compiler writes all of these documentation comments when you build, and is where Visual Studio gets the information it displays in the Intellisense tooltips.

More info on MSDN: [XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: For VS2008 - Check: Properties -> Build -> XML documentation file

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should look at putting your DLL into the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)